# Unexpected warnings issued by ListPointPlot3D when trying to make a plotting with labels (a potential bug)

Tags: plotting, labeling, version-12.1, warning-messages

I was making a very simple plotting with code below:

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{-1.7320508075688776`, -4.`, -1.1796`}, \
{-1.7320508075688772`, -3.`, -1.1796`}, {-1.7320508075688776`, -3.`, 
    1.1796`}, {-1.7320508075688772`, -2.`, 1.1796`}} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

which returned the figure desired, but with mysterious warnings I could not understand.

[image]

Does anyone know what happened? BTW, I use Windows 10 + V 12.1.

---

**Update**

The same code does not show any warnings in V 12.0.

Comment: I see the warnings with v12.1 on a Mac. Some internal calculations are unsuccessful due to the coordinate elements of some points being identical. Since the plot works out anyway, just append `//Quiet` to suppress the warning messages.